# submit a form in json format and update json file

Tags: jquery, json

Following is the json file for customers:
https://we4cs.myshopify.com/admin/customers.json

I have a html form that should get submitted and update the json file. How do i do it? Please advise.

Following is the json file that is customers.json

```
{"customers":[{"accepts_marketing":false,"orders_count":0,"addresses":[{"company":"test","city":"test","address1":"test","name":"test
test","zip":"56576","address2":"test","country_code":"AZ","country":"Azerbaijan","province_code":null,"phone":"54765765878","last_name":"test","province":"hgjghj","first_name":"test"}],"tags":"","id":51036842,"last_name":"test","note":null,"email":"test@test.com","first_name":"test","total_spent":"0.00"},{"accepts_marketing":false,"orders_count":0,"addresses":[{"company":"","city":"newark","address1":"23
smith","name":"gggggggggggggggg
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh","zip":"08786","address2":"","country_code":"US","country":"United
States","province_code":"NJ","phone":"","last_name":"hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh","province":"New
Jersey","first_name":"gggggggggggggggg"}],"tags":"","id":49755872,"last_name":"hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh","note":null,"email":"gregadkins2001@aol.com","first_name":"gggggggggggggggg","total_spent":"0.00"},{"accepts_marketing":false,"orders_count":0,"addresses":[{"company":"dsfsdf","city":"newark","address1":"12
dfsdf","name":"sdfsdf
sdfsdf","zip":"08876","address2":"","country_code":"US","country":"United
States","province_code":"NJ","phone":"","last_name":"sdfsdf","province":"New
Jersey","first_name":"sdfsdf"}],"tags":"","id":47565872,"last_name":"sdfsdf","note":null,"email":"sdfdfsdaf@aol.com","first_name":"sdfsdf","total_spent":"0.00"},{"accepts_marketing":true,"orders_count":0,"addresses":[{"company":"xcvxcvcx","city":"bridgewater","address1":"112
asdasd","name":"zxcxzcxz
cxvxcvxv","zip":"08875","address2":"asdasd","country_code":"US","country":"United
States","province_code":null,"phone":"323123123","last_name":"cxvxcvxv","province":"","first_name":"zxcxzcxz"},{"company":"xcvxcvcx","city":"bridgewater","address1":"112
asdasd","name":"zxcxzcxz
cxvxcvxv","zip":"08875","address2":"asdasd","country_code":"US","country":"United
States","province_code":"NJ","phone":"323123123","last_name":"cxvxcvxv","province":"New
Jersey","first_name":"zxcxzcxz"}],"tags":"","id":40799732,"last_name":"cxvxcvxv","note":"","email":"handful4me@aol.com","first_name":"zxcxzcxz","total_spent":"0.00"}]}
```

Comment: Your link requires authentication. Is there anything you can paste into this question?

Comment: i have pasted the json file contents. Please advise.

Comment: This JSON file is hosted on servers owned by Shopify - there is (probably) no way for you to edit it without using their API (which will probably require a server side solution, as in the first answer)

Answer (score 0):

1. Pick a server side programming language. PHP is popular in the budget world. ASP.NET is popular in the Microsoft world. Java is popular in the Enterprise world. I like Perl. Other options are available.
2. Parse the incoming data. There are libraries that do this for almost any programming language you can name.
3. Apply a file lock to the JSON file
4. Parse the JSON using a library for whatever language you are using.
5. Add the new data to the memory structure you've created
6. Save the file
7. Remove the lock
8. Return an OK message to the client

That said, you would probably be better off generating the JSON on demand and using it only as a transport mechanism. A real database is almost always a better option for storage and manipulation.

Comment: No i cannot use any programming language. It is a shopify ecommerce api. i just want to submit html form and update the values to json file

Comment: You can't update values in a file on the server without software to edit the file.

Answer (score 0):

Basic way of writing to a file, you need [`fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), [`fwrite`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) and of course, [`fclose`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php).

```
<?php

if($_POST['json'])
{
    $open_json = fopen('json_file.json', 'w');

    if($open_json)
    {
        if(fwrite($open_json, $_POST['json'] === FALSE)
        {
            die('failed to write to file');
        }
        fclose($open_json);
    }
    else
    {
        die('failed to open file');
    }
}

?>
```

EDIT: Now that you've mentioned it's from an API, you cannot use this to write to an external server.